# Problem solving strategies for Measure theory (soft question)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, lebesgue-integral

I'm a beginner in learning Measure theory. I would like to ask are there some common problem solving tricks in Measure theory.

For example, usually when I'm doing a measure theory problem, once I rewrite a set into simpler sets, the question is basically solved. So I guess an example trick would be "measure theory problems are mostly about rewriting sets".

Also, the following seems to be a general procedure for proving integral identities/theorems:

1. prove it for indicators $1_A$
2. linearity proves it for simple functions
3. monotone convergence theorem proves it for non-negative measurable functions

Are there any other tricks? Also, are my tricks common/useful? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be helpful: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/245a-problem-solving-strategies/

Comment: @kieransquared Thanks a lot! I just wonder if there're more specific tricks to measure theory. Terry Tao's tricks seem to be for real analysis in general.

Comment: Three that I can think of without putting much effort into this (because I'm busy with other things right now) are **[1]** the [good sets principle](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22good+sets+principle%22+site:math.stackexchange.com), and **[2]** a principle (which I can't think of a name for) that involves making use of the fact that uncountably many positive real numbers cannot have a finite sum (monotone functions have at most countably many discontinuities, a pairwise disjoint collection of positive measure sets is at most countable, etc.), and **[3]** *Littlewood's three principles*.

Comment: @HIH Even though they’re labeled as real analysis, they’re primarily measure theory tricks; they even appeared in Terry Tao’s measure theory book (which you should look at if you’re looking for measure theory intuition)